# terdata fastlod will work even when there is no data in the file?

Tags: teradata

I was curious to know whether teradata FastLoad works fine(loaded with zero rows) when there is no data in the input file  or  the fastload will be aborted saying there is no data in the file

Comment: Don't know; the scripts I use check the file size before attempting FASTLOAD and never use it for less than 200,000 rows.  Why don't you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: Will the input file exist as a zero length file or will it be missing?

Comment: the file will be of zero length with an audit file tooo

Answer (score 0):

Fastload works fine when there is no data in the input file. Fastload will not be aborted. The table will be created without any data.